# Can't activate Hyper-V on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, virtual-machine, hyper-v

A few days ago I updated my Windows installation from "Windows 10 Home" to "Windows 10 Education", because I've got a free Key from my school. However, if I try to install the Windows Feature "Hyper-V" The Computer restarts and get stuck at 32%. After 2 - 3 minutes it says "This Feature can't install (or something like this)". Next I've opened the Event Viewer and saw the following Errors:

1. HAXM can't work on system without VT support.
2. HAXM Failed to init VMX
3. The "IntelHaxm" service was not started due to the following error: A device connected to the system does not work.

I've searched the web and couldn't find any working solution. I've also downloaded multiple programs to test if my computer is ready for VM installation and I couldn't find any issue. Below I've attached some testing results and photos from my BIOS:

[Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA4aG.png)

[SecurAble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHLu3.png)

[BIOS - System Management Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgqZI.jpg)

[BIOS - Processor Informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReYdM.jpg)

[BIOS - Processor Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5k09.jpg)

These are the last 4 Lines from "systeminfo.exe":

Anforderungen für Hyper-V:
Erweiterungen für den VM-Überwachungsmodus: Ja
Virtualisierung in Firmware aktiviert: Ja
Adressübersetzung der zweiten Ebene: Ja
Datenausführungsverhinderung verfügbar: Ja

Here's what I've already tried:

1. I retried the Installation like 10 times.
2. I've updated my BIOS version to the newest available version for my Mainboard.
3. I've tried to install Hyper-V using Powershell
4. I ran two commands which I unfortunately don't remember. I've also found these two commands as a solution for Hyper-V Problems and I guess it's to check the hard disk.

My system:

Mainboard: ASUS Z97-K

CPU: Intel Core i7 4790

RAM: 32.0 GB

Free Hard Disk Space on System Drive: 70GB (should be enough ;))

Comment: "or something like this" - Please provide the exact message.  Please translate any non-English text in your question to English.